# The Stack Overflow user survey says "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired."

Tags: support

I go through the link in the banner that says "Take our short survey". This points to `https://stackoverflow.com/survey/site-satisfaction/redirect` and that redirects to `to https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/<some token>?Code=LOG`

The following page reads:

> You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired.

[image: Screenshot of the page with the Stack Overflow logo and the text "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired."]

I've not *filled in* the survey yet. It's possible I've clicked the link before. I can't actually remember if I did or not, but it's possible I've *opened* the survey. I don't know if this counts as "completing" it.

Is the survey wrong or am I unable to fill it in and submit it any more?

Comment: Seems as if opening the survey starts a timer, which if it expires, submits your partially answered ones.

Comment: Indeed, I am sorry, since the last banner I saw was for the Through the Loop, I assumed that's what you're talking about. I suppose I can clean my comments now, as they are not relevant.

Comment: @Adinia no worries. I myself thought it was the same thing, so I was confused why would it wouldn't work but then I also found the link from the blog post was different.