# Survey - "You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired" - Again

Tags: bug, survey

I was presented with the blue banner to take the survey, and then clicking on the banner I was taken to a page for the survey, told I needed to enable JavaScript from `qualtics.com` and when the page refreshed, I was presented with:

> [image]

Searching, I found a similar post from 2019, but that question from 3 years past shouldn't be the same issue, despite displaying the same error page. [Earlier Question Describing Problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391738/the-stack-overflow-user-survey-says-you-have-either-already-completed-the-surve).

I don't know what the issue is, or if this is related to the up/down status of the site today, but if you are attempting to take the same type of survey I've answered each year for the past 7 or so years, then there is an issue if `qualtrics.com` JavaScript code isn't already enabled.

It may be for some completely different reason, but that is the only thing that appears to explain what happened. Thought I would report it just in case there was an issue.